# Yii: computing aggregate by date

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a simple model in Yii 1.1:

```
Expense

amount: int
date: string
```

How do I compute an aggregate by *date* using build-in Yii capabilities?

**In other words** I would like to get a result of the following query using Yii:

```
SELECT
  date, SUM(amount) AS dateAmount

FROM
  tbl_expense

GROUP BY
  date

ORDER BY
  date DESC
```

Comment: The date is never be in string format

Answer (score 3):

I have explored 2 ways for executing query,

First:

```
$list= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT date, SUM(amount) AS dateAmount
FROM tbl_expense
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC')->queryAll();
var_dump($list->getData());
```

Second: 
(Normally used to provide dataprovider to Gridview and Listview)

```
$select = "SELECT date, SUM(amount) AS dateAmount
FROM tbl_expense
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC";

$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($select,
array(
    'pagination'=>false,
    'params'=>$sqlParam
   )
);
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
```

Comment: That'll work, but it's an SQL. Is there an Yii-way to solve the task?

Comment: CDbCriteria is option which use Active Record. But for SUM, I'm not getting the expected answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use criteria

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'date, SUM(amount) dateAmount';
$criteria->group = 'date';


$model=Expense::model()->find($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use criteria

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'date, SUM(amount) dateAmount';
$criteria->group = 'date';


$model=Expense::model()->find($criteria);
```

**AND**
add property `dateAmount` to the model class.

```
class SomeClass extends CActiveRecord {
  public $dateAmount;
  ...
}
```